# C, debugger breakpoints on simple if else statement

Tags: c, if-statement, codeblocks

I'm very new to coding, I'm editing a simple C function in CodeBlocks. I'm getting a red error dot next to "else", I could't spot any problem with my code, perhaps its something I have overlooked. Please help, thanks!

```
int             isZero  (float f)
{
  unsigned int  u = *(unsigned int*)&f;

    if ((u== 0x0) || (u==0x80000000) );
        return 1;
    else
        return 0;

    return (EXIT_SUCCESS);

}
```

Comment: it's you who is setting the breakpoint, isn't it?

Comment: Also, keep in mind that with the semicolon problem fixed; the `return (EXIT_SUCCESS)` will never be reached, either.

Comment: @Actorclavilis thanks you are golden :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You've got an extra semicolon there.

Remove the one from the end of `if ((u== 0x0) || (u==0x80000000) );`

The compiler reads the `;` as a single statement doing nothing; and considers that the contents of the `if` block. The next statement is `return 1;`, which will *always* execute. When the compiler sees the `else`, it can't find the `if` that goes with it because that `if` block got closed with the first semicolon.

The compiler parses this as

```
int             isZero  (float f)
{
  unsigned int  u = *(unsigned int*)&f;

    if ((u== 0x0) || (u==0x80000000)
        /* do nothing */;

    return 1;

    else /* what does this go with? */
        return 0;

    return (EXIT_SUCCESS);
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Watch out for *all* semicolons. There's one more than you want.

Answer (score 1):

When you put a ; after an if clause it means that the if is an empty block.Therefore whether the statement is true or false the statement next to if is always excecuted.So your code

```
if ((u== 0x0) || (u==0x80000000) );
    return 1;
```

evaluates to

```
if ((u== 0x0) || (u==0x80000000) )
   {   //empty block
     }
    return 1;        //always excecuted
```

Therefore the else part is never excecuted and the compiler does not see a if statement to relate this else to so you get an error.